# How to execute single Jenkins job on multiple platforms with different parameters?

Tags: jenkins

I have created one build job in Jenkins. I want to use that same job to run on multiple nodes but with different job parameter.

Comment: Different parameters or different values for the original job's parameters?

Comment: Yes I mean different parameter values for each node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Create a new multyjob job, in the build section create a Multijob phase, and trigger your job with "Pre defined parameters" and "Node label parameter" to specify the node to run on, and the values of the parameters you want to trigger your job with.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out. Will get back to you.

Comment: Hi,
I have installed the MultiJob plugin as suggested.
I created a MultiType job project as well.
Then I selected multi phase option and selected predefined parameter option as well.
Unfortunately I am not seeing 'Node label parameter' option.
Please suggest.

Comment: Do I need to install Node Label Parameter Plugin as well ?

Comment: After Installing the Node Label parameter plugin I got the Node option as well.

Comment: Have one more doubt. I have three phase jobs now with different node and parameters list. The Actual commands (Suppose windows batch process) which has to be executed in each phase job. How that will be associated or picked up.
If I add one windows batch command process build step, if that going to be shared by all the three phase jobs or how it will.
Please suggest.

Comment: Ok I got it. The Phase JOB name will point to that particular job itself where we have defined the build steps to be executed.

Comment: Hey,  sorry, different time zones :) anything I can help now? What's the status?

Comment: No Problem. Just want to know, if Jenkins itself will take care of generating unique ID for the each phase job. Also if separate email notification can be send on success or failure of each phase job. If this is possible ?

Comment: Sure, just define as a post build operation the email notification in the job you are triggering. You can send system email or install the editable email plugin

Comment: Hi, need help. My base job has 'Execute Windows Batch Process' build step which has command 'perl abc.pl arg1 ar2'
arg1 here is configuration file and arg is some name.
I have to call this base job multiple times from the Multi phase jobs but arguments will always differ.
Can I pass these parameters from the MutiJob ?

Comment: I have figured out the above issue somehow. But have another one. jenkin's phase jobs not running in parallel. Can you suggest on this.

Comment: You need to define the triggering under each phase. Everything inside a phase rub in parallel, phases running serially... Good luck!

Comment: Hi couldn't understand completely. I have defined one phase, under which I have added two jobs.(Each job is pointing to different node and parameter). Now on executing I notice two things.
1. Jobs are not running in parallel.
2. after the first phase job is getting complete, the second phase job is not running on the defined node and predefined parameters. Instead running on master itself.
What do you mean by triggering under each phase?
Please help.

Comment: You did alright in the phase. in the job you triggered make sure to mark "execute concurrent builds". regarding the master, don't send "build on the same node", send "Node Label parameter". make sure that in your child job you didn't restrict it to run on specific node.

Comment: Listen, I can't debug it from here. you need to do some reading on how to specify node, how to send node label and how to run jobs in parallel, you will benefit from it much more than I can help you.... best of luck.

Comment: Hi, I have not mark "execute concurrent builds" remaining settings were as it is it as you mentioned. I noticed, we need to put one executor limit on each node as well to make this happen. Thanks for all your help. Really appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have a plugin: "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin" - install it and you can manage how many runs you can run in parallel, and how many runs per node, so you won't have to limit your executors to one on each slave.

Comment: Also - No worries mate! I would be happy to help, but it'll be helpful if you added screenshots to your question and it's great that you're trying to solve it as well. I hope it's working well now. if so - can I please ask you the favor of marking it as the right answer and mark any useful comment in this thread? You can up-vote it on the left of it :) Thanks!